# No sound on Thinkpad Thunderbolt 3 dock, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I'm having trouble getting sound from the headphone jack of my thinkpad TB3 dock.

The audio interface is detected by pulseaudio, but there is no sound coming through when I define it as the output via `pavucontrol`.

Output of `pacmd list-sinks`:

```
2 sink(s) available.
  * index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9959
    volume: front-left: 51116 /  78% / -6.48 dB,   front-right: 51116 /  78% / -6.48 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 2
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC3266 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC3266 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xed128000 irq 183"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a171"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC3266"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0298,102807be,00100103 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
    index: 2
    name: <alsa_output.usb-Lenovo_ThinkPad_Thunderbolt_3_Dock_USB_Audio_000000000000-00.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9049
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 28.47 ms
    max request: 4 KiB
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    monitor source: 5
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 23.22 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.usb-Lenovo_ThinkPad_Thunderbolt_3_Dock_USB_Audio_000000000000-00>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock USB"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Lenovo ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock USB at usb-0000:0b:00.0-1, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:0b:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.6/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:01.0/0000:09:00.0/0000:0a:00.0/0000:0b:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-Lenovo_ThinkPad_Thunderbolt_3_Dock_USB_Audio_000000000000-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "17ef"
        device.vendor.name = "Lenovo"
        device.product.id = "306a"
        device.product.name = "ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock USB Audio"
        device.serial = "Lenovo_ThinkPad_Thunderbolt_3_Dock_USB_Audio_000000000000"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock USB Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
        alsa.components = "USB17ef:306a"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    ports:
        analog-output: Analog Output (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

    active port: <analog-output>
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by upgrading to kernel 4.5.9